# Duration of use for green smoothies

Tags: smoothie, greens

I make green smoothie in the morning and I dont want to do it again in the evening.
  Is it fine if I use the same smoothie in the evening or there are some problems.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Shan! If you wouldn't mind sharing, it may be helpful if you would edit your question and add the recipe or at least the main ingredients of your smoothie. That way people will know what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem that I've had in the past with making smoothies ahead of time is getting the right consistency because many smoothie recipes rely on ice or frozen fruit to thicken them and thus are not great after several hours in the refrigerator.

I found and have been been playing with a make-ahead recipe that includes oatmeal and chia seeds placed dry in the blender and processed to the consistency of flour to thicken the smoothie, which means you can make them ahead of time without sacrificing thickness.

Recipe source: http://www.theyummylife.com/Oatmeal_Smoothies

Comment: This does in fact appear to address the question, as it names and address a possible issue with preparing smoothies ahead of time.

Comment: How long ahead of time can you make them? At least morning to evening as the OP wanted?

Comment: Yes, I've made them a couple days in advance without any noticeable change in quality.  I put them in jars and do fill to the top to minimize oxidation as MandoMando suggested.

Comment: Sorry for deleting your answer twice; I didn't notice the connection you were implying between texture change and storing the smoothie. I stand corrected and thank the other mods who caught my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your ingredients are reasonably fresh and you refrigerate the smoothie over the day then it should be fine to save it to the evening. It should keep in the fridge for at least a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be fine.

The best is to fill a container to the top and cover it tightly so it's not exposed to air.

That will minimize the oxidization and keep flavor and nutrient's intact.  Otherwise you'll see a deeper green/brown color change.